# ROS Answers SE migration: SLAM in gazebo

Tags: slam, gazebo, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to obtain SLAM maps using gazebo, I followed this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/simulator_gazebo/Tutorials/TeleopErraticSimulation).

Using the command,

> roslaunch erratic_navigation_apps demo_2dnav_slam.launch

and

> rosrun erratic_teleop erratic_keyboard_teleop

The teleoperation works nicely (using WASD keys), though somewhat slowly. However, **I am not able to obtain any maps**. I have previously used [stage with gmapping & mapserver](http://www.ros.org/wiki/stage/Tutorials/MakingMapsUsingStagesWanderController) to obtain SLAM (as a pgm image file), however gazebo seems rather different.

Also, hoping that this method for the SLAM map starts to work - can this method, specifically meant for the erratic robot be used for other robots ?

Any help is most appreciated.

[image]

**UPDATE**: Solved it ! scroll down for my answer

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12636/slam-in-gazebo/) by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1108 on 2012-01-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

how you try to get the map?
try to use rviz for looking it.

---

Originally posted by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) with karma: 471 on 2012-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2012-01-16**:
@Arkapravo yes :)

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-01-16**:
@noonv You are from Kalingrad, must be a romantic place ..... Kant's city ! ... :-) .... I do recall the '7 Bridges of Konigsberg' problem, which is attributed to Euler ! :-)

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-01-16**:
@noonv though that is not what I want, but your suggestion is sure worth a try - Thank you ! .... but probably it will not be a true SLAM mapping ! ..... I will try it and see !

**Comment by [noonv](https://answers.ros.org/users/20/noonv/) on 2012-01-16**:
sure, but you could save it via "rosrun map_server map_saver -f /tmp/my_map"

**Comment by [Arkapravo](https://answers.ros.org/users/198/arkapravo/) on 2012-01-16**:
@noonv the rviz map is not what I am looking for, I want a pgm map - a SLAM like map, the rviz map vanishes with time.